# Monitoring and Evaluation in github projects

Tags: github, project-management

We use GitHub Project to manage as it is simple and easy to integrate with git comments. I couldn't find a way to analyze the performance of the jobs? How can we get reports related to the monitoring and evaluation of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Project management inside GitHub is not catering to the evaluation of the project. You can use third-party project management applications that can be integrated with GitHub seamlessly. One example is http://hubstaff.com